# sparse vector in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

I have some code, using the class vector, which I want to implement with a vector that implements sparse vectors (i.e. instead of recording the elements in an array of the vector's length, including 0's, it would only include the non-zero tables in a look-up table).

Is there any sparse vector class in C++ that makes use of the same interface that vector does? (that will make refactoring much easier.)

Comment: @BenjaminI would have to implement it myself, was looking for a C++11/STL implementation of a vector class that uses the same interface like vector.

Comment: Not an answer, but what are the elements in the vector, how big is the vector and are you sure you need a sparse implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brendan is right to observe that logically a vector provides a map from index to value. An `std::vector` accomplishes this mapping with a simple array. But there are other options.

- `std::unordered_map` has amortized O(1) time operations and seems like a natural alternative.
- `std::map` has O(logn) operations, but the constants are smaller and there are more years of optimizations behind this. In practice it may be faster depending on your application.
- [SparseHash](https://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/) has an STL-compatible hashtable implementation that claims to be better than a standard `unordered_map`.
- [C++ BTree](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/) again offers an STL-compatible `map`, but one that uses btrees instead of binary trees. They claim significantly [improved memory (50-80%) and time](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2013/01/c-containers-that-save-memory-and-time.html).
- [BitMagic](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/) offers an implementation of a sparse *bit* vector. Think a sparse `std::bitset`. If this fits your needs it offers really significant improvements over all the other approaches.
- Finally the classical approach to a sparse vector is to use *two* vectors, one for the index and one for the values. So you have an `std::vector<uint> ind;` and a `std::vector<value_type> val;`.

None of these have *exactly* the same interface as a `std::vector`, but the differences are pretty small and you could easily write a small wrapper. For example, for the map classes you would want to keep track of the size and overload `size()` to return that number instead of the number of non-empty elements. Indeed, Boost's [mapped_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_sparse.htm) that Brendan links to does exactly this: it wraps a map-like class in a vector-like interface.

A drop-in replacement that works in all cases is impossible (because a `std::vector` is in nearly all cases assumed to degenerate into an array, eg. `&vector[0]`, and often this *is* used). Also most users who are interested in the sparse cases are also interested in taking advantage of the sparsity, hence need it exposed. For example, your sparse vector's iterator would have to iterate over *all* elements, including the empties, which is simply wasteful. The whole point of a sparse structure is to skip all that. If your algorithms can't handle that then you leave a lot of potential gains on the table.

Comment: +1 for a good survey. But I would quibble with your assertion that `std::map` has "smaller constants" than a hash table. You may be right for tiny containers, but for large containers that "O(log n)" is counting random pointer chasing, which means performance death on modern hardware because they dodge/thrash the caches. I personally have never encountered a case where `map` outperformed `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 4):

Boost has a [sparse vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector_sparse.htm). I don't think one exists in the standard library.

[`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is probably a better choice though in the long run though, unless you're already using Boost. The main annoyance in refactoring will be that `size()` means something different in a map vs. sparse array. Range-based `for` loops should make that easier to deal with though.